# Adding to the End of a Cell Array

Tags: matlab

I have a 12X1 cell array that holds character strings in each cell. I have also defined four string variables and I wish to add these to the end of the cell array so that it becomes a 16X1 array. I have posted below my code on how I append the four variables; but I am trying to learn this language as best as I can and I am curious if there is a more "elegant" way of appending those variables than what I have written.

```
        elseif (ext == '.s3p')
            %Read in file to be analyzed; convert to string format so
            %that the strsplit function can be used
            inFile = textread(thisFile, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n'); %#ok<DTXTRD>   
            strForm = string(inFile);
            cellOut = arrayfun(@(x) strsplit(x, ' '), strForm, 'UniformOutput', false);

            %Find the end of the meta data and where the Option line of
            %the .s3p file begins (denoted by a '#'). Convert Option
            %line to string for parsing.
            metaDataEndLine = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(inFile, 'Measurements'))) - 1; %#ok<STRCLFH>
            opLine = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(inFile, '#'))); %#ok<STRCLFH>
            opStr = cellstr(cellOut{opLine});

            %Generate meta-data character strings to be printed to the
            %output file. File format can be generalized such that each
            %column corresponds to spefied data unit (i.e. frequency is
            %always the second col).
            metaFreq   = opStr(1,2);
            metaParam  = opStr(1,3);
            metaFormat = opStr(1,4);
            metaResist = opStr(1,6);

            %Genereate a cell array that houses the up-front data
            %provided by the file. Remove unnecessary chars.
            metaDataPrintFile = strForm(1:metaDataEndLine);
            metaDataPrintFile = cellfun(@(x)erase (x, '!'), metaDataPrintFile, 'UniformOutput', false);
            metaDataPrintFile = cellfun(@(x)erase (x, 'Correction: '), metaDataPrintFile, 'UniformOutput', false);

            %Add data to the class array metaPrint. Append string
            %variables generated above.
            this.metaPrint = metaDataPrintFile;
            this.metaPrint{length(this.metaPrint) + 1}      = strcat('Freq = ', metaFreq);
            this.metaPrint{length(this.metaPrint) + 2} = strcat('Parameter = ', metaParam);
            this.metaPrint{length(this.metaPrint) + 3} = strcat('Format = ', metaFormat);
            this.metaPrint{length(this.metaPrint) + 4} = strcat('Input Resistance = ', metaResist);     
        end %if
```

Also, if you see anything else that I could do to make my code more effecient I am all ears!

Thank you in advance and please let me know if there is any other additional information that I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code, simplified:

```
c = cell(12,1);
c{length(c) + 1} = 'a';
c{length(c) + 2} = 'b';
c{length(c) + 3} = 'c';
c{length(c) + 4} = 'd';
```

Let's look at what it does:

```
length(c)
% ans =  22
```

Oops! The first line adds one element; the second line adds an element 2 past the end, adding an empty element then the string; the third line adds an element 3 past the end, adding two empty elements and then the string; etc. -- Note that `length(c)` is evaluated on the extended array every time!

What you want to do is this:

```
c = cell(12,1);
c{length(c) + 1} = 'a';
c{length(c) + 1} = 'b';
c{length(c) + 1} = 'c';
c{length(c) + 1} = 'd';
```

Or more simply

```
c = cell(12,1);
c{end + 1} = 'a';
c{end + 1} = 'b';
c{end + 1} = 'c';
c{end + 1} = 'd';
```

Here we're appending one element each time. To prevent increasing the array size 4 times, you can assign those in reverse order:

```
c = cell(12,1);
c{end + 4} = 'd';
c{end - 1} = 'c';
c{end - 2} = 'b';
c{end - 3} = 'a';
```

This time we're appending 4 elements in the first statement, and filling them in afterwards.

Yet another alternative is

```
c = cell(12,1);
c(end + (1:4)) = {'a','b','c','d'};
```

(note the round brackets for indexing here). We're now appending 4 elements in one go.

Comment: Beautiful! Just what I was looking for.